# tikz error with "file scanning use of tikz cc parse factor"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I get an error message if I execute the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\mytheta{23.43}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0) -- (0, 1.3) -- cycle;
    \draw (3,0) -- +(1, 1.2) -- ($ (0, 1.3)+(1, 1.2) $) -- (0, 1.3);
    \draw (2.5, 0) arc (180:180-\mytheta:0.5);
    \node at ($ (3,0) + (180- 0.5*\mytheta:0.7) $) {$\theta$};
    \coordinate (origin) at (2.5, 1.2);
    \draw[rotate=-\mytheta] (origin) -- +(0.6, 0) node[right] {$x$}
    (origin) node[above] {$y$} -- + (0, -0.6) node[below] {$z$}
    (origin) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (origin) circle (0.3pt);
    \coordinate (apex) at (1,1.6);
    \draw[dotted] (apex) -- +(10:0.4) coordinate (mup) (apex) -- +(-10:0.4) coordinate (mdown);
    \draw (mup) -- +(10:0.4) (mdown) -- +(-10:0.4);

    \draw ($ .5*(mup) + .5*(mdown) $) circle ({.2*tan(10)} and {.4*tan(10)});
    \draw ($ (apex) + {(.8*tan(10), 0)} $) circle ({.4*tan(10)} and {.8*tan(10)});
    \draw[dotted] (apex) -- +(-\mytheta:1) coordinate (Omega) (apex) -- +(180-\mytheta:0.2);
    \draw ($ (Omega) + (-\mytheta-40:0.3) $) arc (-\mytheta-40:-\mytheta+40:0.2); 
    \node at ($ (Omega) + (-\mytheta:0.5) $) {$\Omega$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How should I solve this problem? Maybe the problem is due to the latter part of the code.

Comment: The problem is that `($ (apex) + {.8*tan(10)} $)` doesn't really make sense, you're adding a single number to a coordinate. What were you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you. In fact I was about to write (.8*tan(10), 0). However, I still  get an error message after revising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in `($ (apex) + {.8*tan(10)} $)`, as this is adding a single number to a coordinate. I understand you meant to write `($ (apex) + ({.8*tan(10)},0) $)`, in which case the code compiles fine, and the output is

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\mytheta{23.43}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0) -- (0, 1.3) -- cycle;
    \draw (3,0) -- +(1, 1.2) -- ($ (0, 1.3)+(1, 1.2) $) -- (0, 1.3);
    \draw (2.5, 0) arc (180:180-\mytheta:0.5);
    \node at ($ (3,0) + (180- 0.5*\mytheta:0.7) $) {$\theta$};
    \coordinate (origin) at (2.5, 1.2);
    \draw[rotate=-\mytheta] (origin) -- +(0.6, 0) node[right] {$x$}
    (origin) node[above] {$y$} -- + (0, -0.6) node[below] {$z$}
    (origin) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (origin) circle (0.3pt);
    \coordinate (apex) at (1,1.6);
    \draw[dotted] (apex) -- +(10:0.4) coordinate (mup) (apex) -- +(-10:0.4) coordinate (mdown);
    \draw (mup) -- +(10:0.4) (mdown) -- +(-10:0.4);

    \draw ($ .5*(mup) + .5*(mdown) $) circle ({.2*tan(10)} and {.4*tan(10)});
    \draw ($ (apex) + ({.8*tan(10)},0) $) circle ({.4*tan(10)} and {.8*tan(10)});
    \draw[dotted] (apex) -- +(-\mytheta:1) coordinate (Omega) (apex) -- +(180-\mytheta:0.2);
    \draw ($ (Omega) + (-\mytheta-40:0.3) $) arc (-\mytheta-40:-\mytheta+40:0.2); 
    \node at ($ (Omega) + (-\mytheta:0.5) $) {$\Omega$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```